# Exception propagation from Task.StartNew

Tags: c#, async-await, task, semaphore

Consider this code:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAmazonMwsNotifications(ScAmazonNotificationType scAmazonNotificationType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var scAmazonSqsMwsNotificationsManagmentClientRequestBuilder = _scServiceLocator.GetInstance<IScAmazonSqsMwsNotificationsManagmentClientRequestBuilder>();

        var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<string>();

        try
        {
            StartReceiveMessagesAsync(blockingCollection, cancellationToken, scAmazonNotificationType, scAmazonSqsMwsNotificationsManagmentClientRequestBuilder);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw //this catch is never called;
        }

        return blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable(cancellationToken);
    }  


private async void StartReceiveMessagesAsync(BlockingCollection<string> blockingCollection, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ScAmazonNotificationType scAmazonNotificationType, IScAmazonSqsMwsNotificationsManagmentClientRequestBuilder scAmazonSqsMwsNotificationsManagmentClientRequestBuilder)
    {
        var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(15);

        var receiveMessageRequest = scAmazonSqsMwsNotificationsManagmentClientRequestBuilder.BuildReceiveMessageRequest(scAmazonNotificationType);

        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Test");

                    var receiveMessageResponse = _scAmazonSqsClientWrapper.ReceiveMessageAsync(receiveMessageRequest, cancellationToken).Result;

                    foreach (var result in receiveMessageResponse.Messages.Select(p => p.Body))
                    {
                        blockingCollection.Add(result, cancellationToken);
                    }

                    var deleteFromQueueRequest = scAmazonSqsMwsNotificationsManagmentClientRequestBuilder.BuildBatchDeleteMessageRequest(scAmazonNotificationType, receiveMessageResponse.Messages.Select(p => p.ReceiptHandle).ToArray());

                    _scAmazonSqsClientWrapper.DeleteMessageBatchAsync(deleteFromQueueRequest, cancellationToken);
                }
                finally
                {
                    semaphore.Release(1);
                }
            }, cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, new ThreadPerTaskScheduler());
        }
    }
```

If the exception is thrown inside the task delegate it's never propagated to the calling method. I can't await for task inside the semaphore, because in this case semaphore will be blocked by the awaited task. Is there any way to propagate the exception to the calling method.

Comment: May I ask why you are using Task.Factory.StartNew?  FYI - You don't seem to be using Task.Factory.StartNew  correctly... http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: Because I want to specify a custom task scheduler I don't want to use the thread pool. My task scheduler starts a new thread on task queue. And not waiting for thread to be available. It gave me about 50% gain in performance.

Comment: That's likely true in the starting phase as the Threadpool delays creation of the new threads (only about one per seconds as far as I remember). Depending on your exact scenario, once the pool has a certain size you will gain better performance using the pool.
You can circumvent this problem by setting a higher min thread size. Maybe give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You're running in two problems: 
`async void` has a slightly different error handling in comparision to traditional void methods: Although `StartReceiveMessagesAsync` is called by `GetAmazonMwsNotifications` and it blocks `GetAmazonMwsNotifications` until the first `await` (on an uncompleted Task) is reached, any exceptions from within `StartReceiveMessagesAsync` are never thrown back to `GetAmazonMwsNotifications`. In non UI applications they are always thrown onto the threadpool, bringing the application down (I don't know how UI applications work in that case).

So why doesn't your application die? 
The exception is not thrown onto the stack, it's set onto the Task that is returned by `Task.Factory.StartNew` and this Task is not observed (neither via await nor via .Wait()). At some point the Garbage Collector will run to collect that Task and at that point an `UnobservedTaskException` will be thrown on the appdomain. When this is not observed your application will finally go down.

In my opinion you don't need to offload the code via Task.Run/Task.Factory.StartNew, await the result of `ReceiveMessageAsync` instead of blocking on it and handle exceptions in the `async void` method the "usual" way; just keep in mind that unhandled exceptions will bring down the application.

Comment: Thank you, for explanation. I know all that. I need to await for the task I run to get the exception on my runtime stack. Is there any pattern I can use with semaphore to cycle my task creation and await it in the same time.
Like cycling list and to use Task.WhenOne on the list when task completes remove the task from the list and add a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue with another task with the [OnlyOnFaulted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx/) option (i.e. an exception has been thrown and the task is in the faulted state).

```
.ContinueWith(t => { Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.Message); }, 
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Comment: I can but it still wont propagate the exception, to the calling method. And I really need it to propagate so I can change execution conditions. Like passing different credentials.

Comment: Handle it in the ContinueWith task.